# Ruby on Rails - Integration Test - undefined method "get"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, integration-testing, undefined

I am using Rails version 3.2.12 and I have some issues with my integration test (unit and functional test working perfectly).

I have use the following command to create integration test:

```
rails generate integration_test user_stories
```

Then I have populated the "user_stories_test.rb" file as follows:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserStoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  LineItem.delete_all
  Order.delete_all
  ruby_book = product(:ruby)

  get "/"
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "index"

  xml_http_request :post, '/line_items', product_id: ruby_book.id
  assert_response :success
  cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  assert_equal 1, cart.line_items.size
  assert_equal ruby_book, cart.line_items[0].product

  get "/orders/new"
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "new"

  post_via_redirect "/orders",
                    order: { name: "Dave Thomas",
                             address: "123 The Street",
                             email: "dave@example.com",
                             pay_type: "Check" }
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "index"
  cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  assert_equal 0, cart.line_items.size

  orders = Order.all
  assert_equal 1, orders.size
  order = orders[0]
  assert_equal "Dave Thomas", order.name
  assert_equal "123 The Street", order.address
  assert_equal "dave@example.com", order.email
  assert_equal "Check", order.pay_type
  assert_equal 1, order.line_items.size
  line_item = order.line_items[0]
  assert_equal ruby_book, line_item.product

  mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  assert_equal ["dave@example.com"], mail.to
  assert_equal 'Sam Ruby <depot@example.com>', mail[:from].value
  assert_equal "Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation", mail.subject

end
```

And that's how my "test_helber.rb" file looks like:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
```

First of all, I my fixtures were not loaded, and after I was not able to fix this following [these](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4971) instructions I have ended creating the test data manually like this:

```
  #ruby_book = product(:ruby)

  ruby_book = Product.new
  ruby_book.title = 'Programming Ruby 2.0'
  ruby_book.price =  49.50
  ruby_book.image_url = 'ruby.png'
  ruby_book.description = 'description'
  ruby_book.save!
```

This solves the issue with fixtures loading by now I am getting "method undefined" error on my "get" method. Something more, after I have comment all "get" methods, I am getting the same error on the next method - "xml_http_request".

What I am doing wrong? Why rails is not able to find these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not in the context of a test when you are running this code.

A Test::Unit case would have the format of the following:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserStoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def test_it_works_as_it_should  # <-- this is the part you're missing!
    # Your test code goes here
  end
end
```

Just putting the code for your test in a class does not do all the proper setup that Test::Unit expects for your test to run correctly.

More information on testing in Rails:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing